# SQLite error near "WITH"

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

i try to update data with this code

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
public static string filename = CGlobalVar.CurrentMissionFolder + @"\DBase\BMS_Ops";

conn.Open();

SQLiteCommand scom = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
scom.CommandText = "WITH NewNames(SatuanID, ParentAddr, IpSlave, row_Num) AS (select SatuanID, ParentAddr, IpSlave, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SatuanKawan AS t2 where ParentAddr = " + satuan.wOpsAddr.ToString() + " and t2.SatuanID <= t1.SatuanID) AS row_Num From SatuanKawan AS t1 where ParentAddr = " + satuan.wOpsAddr.ToString() + " ) update SatuanKawan set IpSlave = '" + udpSlave + "' WHERE SatuanID IN ( SELECT SatuanID FROM NewNames WHERE row_Num = " + j + ")";
scom.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();
```

but when execute the code is error

```
SQLite error
near "WITH": syntax error
```

when i try to execute the query in sqlite browser it works fine.

how to fix that?

**EDIT**

This is the value öf scom.CommandText after variables

```
WITH NewNames(SatuanID, ParentAddr, IpSlave, row_Num) AS
  (SELECT SatuanID,
          ParentAddr,
          IpSlave,
     (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM SatuanKawan AS t2
      WHERE ParentAddr = 1
        AND t2.SatuanID <= t1.SatuanID) AS row_Num
   FROM SatuanKawan AS t1
   WHERE ParentAddr = 1)
UPDATE SatuanKawan
SET IpSlave = '192.168.1.101'
WHERE SatuanID IN
    (SELECT SatuanID
     FROM NewNames
     WHERE row_Num = 1)
```

or i use wrong system.data.sqlite.dll?

i confused why this query in c# error, but works when i running database manually in sqlite browser after variables.

**SOLVED**

like laalto say. when try debugging in my app this version return 3.7.10 , different when im debugging with sql browser is version value 3.8.4.2, so im try to search newest version and i found it in http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget and install package system data sqlite version 3.8.5 in my app and it works.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: SQLite version 3 , version 3.8.4.2

Comment: . . Can you edit the question and print out `CommandText` *after* variable substitution?

Comment: What does `SELECT sqlite_version();` return when you run it the same way you run your problematic query?

Comment: no error when i use query `SELECT sqlite_version();` how to see a return query?

Comment: The same way you would read the results from any `SELECT` query.

Comment: i use the query `SELECT sqlite_version();` and return is `3.7.10` different when i running in sqlite browser value is `3.8.4.2` . @laalto

Comment: That's too old and `WITH` queries are not supported.

Comment: i try to search the newer version in http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki but system.data.sqlite error when load dll. `FileLoadException was unhandled`

Comment: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Answer (score 1):

You missed some single quotes:

```
WHERE ParentAddr = " + satuan.wOpsAddr.ToString() + "
```

should probably be

```
WHERE ParentAddr = '" + satuan.wOpsAddr.ToString() + "'
```

And there's another one like it.

One a side note, concatenating your parameters like this is bad for a number of reasons. It's error-prone, can lead to bad performance, and even to vulnerability for SQL-injections. You should parameterize your query instead.

Comment: i change it but still error `SQLite error
near "WITH": syntax error`